# Change color of RaisedButton from theme not working

Tags: flutter, material-design

I tried changing the color of all my RaisedButtons from the `themeData` but it refused to work. All other properties, such as `fontSize` and `fontWeight` changed successfully. The color of the text only changes from black to white when the brightness property of `themeData` is changed to `Brightness.dark`.

Is there a way I can solve this issue? What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my sample code:

```
 return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0XFF212845),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0XFF212845),
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
        buttonColor: Color(0XFFF8D320),
        textTheme:  TextTheme(
          button: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green, // This is not working.
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          )
        )
      ),
      home:MenuPage(),
    );
```

Answer (score 54):

For other people coming to this question, one reason that a button may not change colors is that it is disabled, which happens when you don't have the `onPressed` method set.

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  onPressed: () {}, //                        <-- need to add this
  child: Text(...),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this answer even if it doesn't address the actual question!  This was my issue which brought me here.

Comment: "one reason that a button may not change colors is that it is disabled, which happens when you don't have the onPressed method set."

This fixed it for me

Comment: I am having the same issue and I did everything like all above but I set onPressed method to null and all solutions didn't work but I read your comment and it works for me @Zero

Comment: oh, c'mon! I passed a mock function from parent widget that should be called while I create the widget and it didn't work so I almost lost my mind with this... if doing what I've done, call the callback function like this: `onPressed: () => this.onClick(),` and not like this: `onPressed: this.onClick,`

Comment: I was looking for Theme.of(context).***Color

Answer (score 12):

if you are giving a color to the color property and it doesn't show ,then probably you haven't implemented the onPressed property, because in this state the button will show it's disabled color , which is no color at all.

set it like this:

```
onPressed: () {},
```

giving it an anonymous function like that while not implementing anythig ( or something if you wish) will give it color

Comment: given colors will not reflect till on pressed method not called.

so please call above method it does not mendatory to write anything in method if you want to perform any operation we can write that program here 

onPressed: () {},

Comment: This answer helped me!

Answer (score 7):

Add `buttonTheme` and `accentColor` to your `ThemeData` , like this:

```
  ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color(0XFF212845),
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0XFF212845),
            primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
            buttonColor: Color(0XFFF8D320),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent),
            accentColor: Colors.green,
```

**Updated**

This is the code updated using the new API

```dart
ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
    primary: Color(0XFF212845),
    background: Color(0XFF212845),
    secondary: Colors.yellow,
    surface: Color(0XFFF8D320),
    onSurface: Colors.green,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    onError: Colors.red,
    primaryVariant: Colors.blue,
    secondaryVariant: Colors.blueAccent,
    onBackground: Colors.white,
    onPrimary: Colors.white,
    onSecondary: Colors.black,
    error: Colors.red,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. but is there no way i can change to a different color apart from those gotten through the `ButtonTextTheme` enum?

Comment: I was checking the source code and looks like it use the accentColor if the textTheme of the button is ButtonTextTheme.accent

Comment: yes. That is exactly what is does, so you can't make use of any other color apart from primary, accent and black/white.

Comment: using theme I guess no , but you can set the color directly to your text inside the RaisedButton ( or create your own RaisedButton to include in different pages)

Comment: I guess so too. Thanks for your help. Really grateful!

Comment: This code now deprecated!

Answer (score 3):

Even though primarySwatch might have been added, you still need to add buttonColor to add the color to the buttons, like this:

```
child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          buttonColor: Colors.blue // this is needed
        ),
      ),
```

> primarySwatch - used to configure default values for several fields,
> including: primaryColor, primaryColorBrightness, primaryColorLight,
> primaryColorDark, toggleableActiveColor, accentColor, colorScheme,
> secondaryHeaderColor, textSelectionColor, backgroundColor, and
> buttonColor.

Also, make sure onPressed in your RaisedButton is set:

```
onPressed: () {},
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't customize the RaisedButton() itself, else it will override the ThemeData. If you have customized color property in RaisedButton it will override the properties set in ThemeData.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the above answers are deprecated with the time I have posting this.

```
      theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color(0XFF212845),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0XFF212845),
    primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.green),
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(
          TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: this is not working for me for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way is to declare a `buttonColor` property in your `ThemeData` Widget.

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Pirata',
          primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(71, 86, 87, 1),
          accentColor: Color.fromRGBO(71, 86, 87, 1),
          buttonColor: Color.fromRGBO(238, 238, 238, 1),

        ),
        home: App()))
```